# Find duplicate rows and the file which contains the duplicated row in a large dataframe split over multiple files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bigdata

So I have a big dataframe split in 404 excel files. The dataframe as an ID column, and I have to:

1. Find whether there are duplicate rows
2. In case of a duplicate row, output the two files that contain the duplicated row

For example, suppose that the row with key ID "ID_101" is contained in file #10 and file #209. The script should output "Duplicate row: ID_101 is contained in both file #10 and file #209".

I tried this approach: creating a *set* with all the key ids, and a *dictionary* which maps every id to a file. When I loop through the files and their rows

1. If the ID is in the set, it will lookup the dictionary and output where that row was already found.
2. If, instead, the ID is not in the set, it will add it to the set, and create a new entry in the dictionary that maps that id to the current file

So a MWE would be:

```
import os, sys, pandas

ids_set = set()
ids_map = dict()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for file in files:
        in_file = pandas.read_excel(os.path.join(root, file), header=0, sheet_name="Results")    

        # Check for duplicated companies
        this_ids = list(in_file['BvD ID number'])
        for this_id in this_ids:
            if this_id in ids_set:
                print("ERROR: duplicate ID '{}', already found in '{}'".format(this_id, ids_map[this_id]))
            else:
                ids_set.add(this_id)
                ids_map[this_id] = filen
```

The problem is that, at the 300th something file, I get a MemoryError when I try to access the dictionary, supposedly because it became to large.

How can I achieve my purpose with such a big dataframe?

Comment: Are you trying to find duplicates across files only or those within files also count? Another thing is you can drop `ids_set` and instead check `if this_id in ids_map`.

Comment: @QuangHoang those within files also count. Is looking inside a set faster than looking inside a dictionary?

Comment: I believe It’s the same. Also, you don’t need to create `this_ids`. You can walk through the column itself.

Answer (score 0):

You get a memory error because you are doing it recursively while Pandas is optimized for vectorized operation.

The best way to do it would be to append all your dataframes in a really big dataframe, create a column containing the source file, and to look for duplicates.

Something along the lines of:

```py
df = pandas.DataFrame()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for file in files:
        current_df = pandas.read_excel(filen, header=0, sheet_name="Results")
        current_df["source_file"] = root + file

        df = df.append(current_file, ignore_index=True)
```

And then to get the duplicated rows:

```py
duplicated_df = df[df.duplicated(subset="ID", keep=False)]
print(duplicated_df)
```

I cannot try since I don't have your data and I don't have your exact expected output but something similar should work.

Comment: he's not doing things `recursively`, more like `serially`. If anything, his code requires less memory than yours as it deals with one data frame at a time, not 401.

Comment: @ggrelet Thanks, I have tried that but I cannot read the merged dataframe in memory. I get either a MemoryError with `low_memory=True` and `pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory` with `low_memory=False`